# How to style chrome scrollbar to make it look and behave like firefox

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow, customization

I have the following css in Firefox:

[image]

The same page looks like this in chrome:

[image]

Is there any way to style chrome scrollbar to make it look like firefox?

I'm just using overflow-y: auto and a fixed heigth.

I created a the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/opensas/pen/WNEQNjx) to test it

```css
  ul {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Finance</li>
  <li>Accounting</li>
  <li>Support</li>
  <li>Reports</li>
</ul>
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Finance</li>
  <li>Accounting</li>
  <li>Support</li>
  <li>Reports</li>
</ul>
  
<style>
  ul {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a solution, you can create your own custom scrollbar and use it to ensure the output is the same in all other browsers.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #F2F2F2;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #BDBDBD;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #6E6E6E;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Finance</li>
  <li>Accounting</li>
  <li>Support</li>
  <li>Reports</li>
</ul>
  
<style>
  ul {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
  }
</style>
```

From the [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp):

> Note: Custom scrollbars are not supported in Firefox or in Edge, prior to version 79.

Comment: thanks for this, saved me hours of tinkering!

Comment: Is there any solution to make the chrome and other webkit based browsers scrollbar to behave like Firefox's scrollbar. Like, whenever we hover over the overflowed element the scrollbar shows up smoothly and other elements doesn't adjust their content because of scrollbar's width space.